# How would I rework this Objective-C Strategy pattern in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I saw [this example of the Strategy pattern in Objective-C](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4020453/objective-c-strategy-pattern), but I am curious about setting up the same pattern using Swift.

How would I do something like this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally nothing about your linked example that cannot be directly translated to Swift:

```
class Dog {
    var position: Int = 0
    var strategy: DogStrategy

    init(strategy: DogStrategy) {
        self.strategy = strategy
    }

    func updatePosition() {
        self.position = self.strategy.getNewPositionFromPosition(self.position)
    }
}

class DogStrategy {
    func getNewPositionFromPosition(position: Int) -> Int {
        return position + 2;
    }
}
```

Although, I think this is better implemented and illustrated as a protocol (which is possible in Objective-C as well):

```
protocol DogStrategy {
    func getNewPositionFromPosition(position: Int) -> Int
}

class Dog {
    var position: Int = 0
    var strategy: DogStrategy
    func updatePosition() {
        self.position = self.strategy.getNewPositionFromPosition(self.position)
    }
    init(strategy: DogStrategy) {
        self.strategy = strategy
    }
}

class SlowDogStrategy: DogStrategy {
    func getNewPositionFromPosition(position: Int) -> Int {
        return position + 1;
    }
}

class FastDogStrategy: DogStrategy {
    func getNewPositionFromPosition(position: Int) -> Int {
        return position + 5;
    }
}

var fastDog = Dog(strategy: FastDogStrategy())
var slowDog = Dog(strategy: SlowDogStrategy())
```

Answer (score 2):

(Sixteen months later...)

drewag's answer is good and works just fine but since, in Swift, functions are first class citizens then the answer can be simplified by doing away with the protocol and classes surrounding the strategy definition.  The use of type alias's is optional but contributes towards self documenting code.

```
class Dog {
    var position: Int = 0
    var strategy: DogStrategy
    func updatePosition() {
        position = strategy(position)
    }
    init(strategy: DogStrategy) {
        self.strategy = strategy
    }
}

/// The strategy is implemented by any function that takes a position and returns another.
typealias Position = Int
typealias DogStrategy = (Position) -> Position

// Strategy one.
func slowDogStrategy(position: Position) -> Position {
    return position + 1;
}

// Strategy two,
func fastDogStrategy(position: Position) -> Position {
    return position + 5;
}

var fastDog = Dog(strategy: fastDogStrategy)
var slowDog = Dog(strategy: slowDogStrategy)
```